# Drawing background square and points using opengles 2.0

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm learning OpenGL 2.0 for iPhone.

The first, i'm trying to draw a background with some texture. It works only while i'm not drawing anything else.

Here is code to draw background:

```
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

// Clear the buffer
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, viewFramebuffer);
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

//Draw something here
if (backgroundTextureCreated == YES) {
    static const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,
    };

    static const GLfloat textureVertices[] = {
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f,  1.0f,
        0.0f,  0.0f,
    };

    #warning BG drawing here.

    /*_ddp_positionSlot = glGetAttribLocation(_ddp_program, "position");
    _ddp_inputTextureCoordinateSlot = glGetAttribLocation(_ddp_program, "inputTextureCoordinate");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(_ddp_positionSlot);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(_ddp_inputTextureCoordinateSlot);
    _ddp_TextureUniform = glGetUniformLocation(_ddp_program, "bg");*/

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, BackgroundTexture.id);
    glUniform1i(_ddp_TextureUniform, 0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(_ddp_positionSlot, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(_ddp_positionSlot);
    glVertexAttribPointer(_ddp_inputTextureCoordinateSlot, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, textureVertices);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(_ddp_inputTextureCoordinateSlot);
    glUseProgram(_ddp_program);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}

// Display the buffer
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

And here is code to draw points:

```
- (void)renderLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)start toPoint:(CGPoint)end
{
static GLfloat*     vertexBuffer = NULL;
static NSUInteger   vertexMax = 128;
NSUInteger          vertexCount = 0,
                    count,
                    i;

[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, viewFramebuffer);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, brushTexture.id);

// Convert locations from Points to Pixels
CGFloat scale = self.contentScaleFactor;
start.x *= scale;
start.y *= scale;
end.x *= scale;
end.y *= scale;

// Allocate vertex array buffer
if(vertexBuffer == NULL)
    vertexBuffer = malloc(vertexMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));

// Add points to the buffer so there are drawing points every X pixels
count = MAX(ceilf(sqrtf((end.x - start.x) * (end.x - start.x) + (end.y - start.y) * (end.y - start.y)) / kBrushPixelStep), 1);
for(i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    if(vertexCount == vertexMax) {
        vertexMax = 2 * vertexMax;
        vertexBuffer = realloc(vertexBuffer, vertexMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));
    }

    vertexBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 0] = start.x + (end.x - start.x) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);
    vertexBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 1] = start.y + (end.y - start.y) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);
    NSLog(@"Vertex coords: %f,%f",
          start.x + (end.x - start.x) * (GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count,
            start.y + (end.y - start.y) * (GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count );
    vertexCount += 1;
}

// Load data to the Vertex Buffer Object
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexCount*2*sizeof(GLfloat), vertexBuffer, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

// Draw
glUseProgram(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertexCount);
//glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
// Display the buffer
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}
```

renderLineFromPoint function has been taken from apple GLPaint sample code.

Background drawing stops working when i draw line from point.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a very similar problem.
I was able to draw a texture as background. Whenever I started painting with my fingers on the canvas, the background disappeared (seems to be your problem, too).

My drawing code was all right (and yours seems to be too). The problem was, that after setting the background and before painting with my fingers the method `resizeFromLayer:` got called, which then called `renderBufferStorage:fromDrawable:`. The latter method flushes the backing buffer (see [renderBufferStorage: fromDrawable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/OpenGLES/Reference/EAGLContext_ClassRef/Reference/EAGLContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/EAGLContext/renderbufferStorage%3afromDrawable%3a)).

Since you also use GLPaint as starting point, I guess this could be the cause of your problem, too.

Comment: finally, what it your solution?

Comment: As a first quick fix I commented out the line `[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:layer];` in `resizeFromLayer:`. Seems to be working so far but I didn't test for memory or resizing issues...